# Variable or React State?

Tags: reactjs, state

Still trying to understand React state.

slides won't change so it's not state.

count changes so it's state.

currentSlide changes based on count. Should it be state?

Thank you for any help!

```
const slides = [
  { background: 'blue', heading: 'Hi' },
  { background: 'pink', heading: 'Hola' }
];

function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let currentSlide = slides[count]; // should currentSlide be state?

  
  useEffect(() => {
    // interval incrementing count every 10 seconds
  });


  return (
    <div bg={currentSlide.background}>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: See the checklist in step 3 in the react docs on [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to keep it as it is. It is in a way 'derived' state, and you can just keep it as a normal variable.

As an example, imagine you wanted to show count multiple times in a page. This would be fine to do:

```js
function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    // increment count 10 seconds
  })

  const count1 = count + 1
  const count2 = count + 2

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <div>{count1}</div>
      <div>{count2}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or, more succintly:

```js
function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    // increment count 10 seconds
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <div>{count + 1}</div>
      <div>{count + 2}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code, you declared `currentSlide` as a variable, not a state.
So, when `currentSlide` is updated, re-rendering doesn't occur.
If you feel burdened to use `currentSlide` as a state, you can use `useMemo` hook instead.

This is an example of using `useMemo` base on your code.

```
const slides = [
  { background: 'blue', heading: 'Hi' },
  { background: 'pink', heading: 'Hola' }
];

function Home() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const currentSlide = React.useMemo(()=>{
    return slides[count];
  }, [count]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // interval incrementing count every 10 seconds
  });


  return (
    <div bg={currentSlide.background}>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thanks kyun. I'll checkout useMemo if I have to use state.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to explpain to you the logic behind it in a simplified manner
if you are put in a situation where your logic is an "if condition" then you will be using the "STATE"
an example to that would be as follows

```
 if(myState==something){
i will do that
}else{
i will do something else
}
```

Overall whenever you are using a conditional logic you have to use this type of state